# PDF and CDF of $x$ and $y$ coordinates of a random vector.

Tags: probability-distributions, vectors, normal-distribution, density-function

I have a random vector where the magnitude ($M$) and angle ($\Theta$) are *independent* and normally distributed

\begin{align}
M &\sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2) \\
\Theta &\sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)
\end{align}

The Cartesian $x$ and $y$ coordinates for the vector are therefore also random variables:

\begin{align}
X &= M\cos \Theta \\
Y &= M\sin \Theta
\end{align}

How can I derive PDF and CDF of $X$ and $Y$?

The aim is to be able to work out the probability of a vector falling within certain $x$ and $y$ bounds.

$$P((x_1<X<x_2) \cap (y_1<Y<y_2))$$

*Edit*: as pointed out in the comments, $M$ cannot be negative, so should be modelled either as a $\chi_1$ distribution or a half-normal distribution.

Comment: You can't do anything unless you know the joint density of $M$ and $\Theta$. Do you know if they're independent? If not, then more information is needed.

Comment: Also, $M$ is magnitude. How does it make any sense for $M$ to be normally distributed? If $M$ is normally distributed, what you are in fact stating is that $M$ can be negative.

Comment: @Clarinetist yes $M$ and $\Theta$ are independent. Sorry I don't know what the join density is, do you mean the density of $(M+\Theta)$?

Comment: @Clarinetist good point re $M$'s distribution. This is intended to model honeybee [waggle dance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waggle_dance), where both components of the vector, angle **and** magnitude, are normally distributed when conveyed by the bees. Although the magnitude has been looked at only above c. 500m

Comment: @Clarinetist maybe it is better to model $M$ as a Chi-distribution with 1 df,  which cannot be negative?

Comment: That really depends on what you find appropriate, given your domain expertise. You could also use a [half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution). In either situation, I would expect that the problem is going to get ugly rather quickly.

Comment: Are you interested in the exact analytic answer or an approximation?

Comment: @Jan the exact analytic answer would be the most sought after as it is the *ideal* solution (sadly, my maths skill is not up to par to do it myself). Approximation, would of course be acceptable in practice -- but I already have an approximate solution which I have done using a Monte Carlo method.

Comment: For the record, knowing the "PDF and CDF of $X$ and $Y$" would **not** allow you "to work out the probability of a vector falling within certain $x$ and $y$ bounds [that is, to compute probabilities such as] $P(x_1<X<x_2,y_1<Y<y_2)$".

Comment: @Did I see... because $X$ and $Y$ aren't independent...Did I follow a blind alley or could you suggest a way of doing it?

Comment: I understand that, in the end, $M$ is not normal. Is $\Theta$ really normal? A more usual assumption is $\Theta$ uniform on $(0,2\pi)$...

Comment: @Did $\Theta$ is indeed normal.